# How is a const class object different from const data member?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, constants

I have two sample pieces of code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class emp {
    int emp_count;

    public:
        emp() { emp_count=2; }
        int get_employee_count() const { return emp_count; }
};


int main() {
    const emp e1;
    cout << e1.get_employee_count();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine. However, the below code gives an error for trying to change a read-only value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class emp {
    const int emp_count;

    public:
        emp() { emp_count=2; }
        int get_employee_count() const { return emp_count; }
};


int main() {
    emp e1;
    cout << e1.get_employee_count();
    return 0;
}
```

A const class object doesn't let me change the value of the data member, but based on the above example, how is a **const class object** different from a **const data member** as I am able to assign the value in the constructor body in the first piece of code, while the second piece of code restricts me to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

A const class object doesn't allow the value of any of its data members to be modified outside the constructor. For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class emp {
public:
    int emp_count; // Made public for demonstration
    emp() { emp_count = 2; }
    int get_employee_count() const { return emp_count; }
};

int main() 
{
    const emp e1;
    emp e2;
    e1.emp_count = 10; // Compiler error

    std::cout << e1.get_employee_count();
    return 0;
}
```

But emp_count can still be modified by the constructor:

```
emp() 
{ 
    emp_count = 2; // This is assignment, not initialization
}
```

A const data member is a data member that cannot be modified after initialization, neither inside the class nor outside the class.

To initialize a data member, just assign a value to it as such:

```
class emp 
{
    const int emp_count = 2;
public:
```

Or initialize it using the constructor as such:

```
class emp 
{
    const int emp_count;
public:
    emp() : emp_count(2) { } // Initialization of emp_count
    int get_employee_count() const { return emp_count; }
};
```

Also, consider not using the following line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as bad practice.

Comment: _"But emp_count can still be modified by the class methods"_ -- This is not correct. Class methods also cannot modify a const object (unless we are talking about modifying only members specifically marked as `mutable` in that object). That's why const objects allow only const methods to be invoked on them. However, constructor/destructor are special. An object's lifetime has not yet begun before its constructor finishes execution. That's why you can modify non-const members of a const object from inside its constructor. The same with destructor: object lifetime ends once dtor starts executing.

Comment: I actually meant to say the constructor, as I gave example of a constructor too, I just wrote class methods by mistake (just noticed). Correction made☑.

Answer (score 1):

`emp_count=2;` is not initialization, it is an assignment. Even if it happens in a constructor. And one cannot assign to const objects.

Use the initializer list to initialize const members:

```
emp(): emp_count(2) {}
```

Even better is to use in-class initialization for constants:

```
class emp{ 
    int emp_count=2;
    public:
    int get_employee_count() const {return emp_count;}
};
```

This has the advantage of rule-of-zero and it propagates the value to all constructors if any are defined explicitly.